# Obter string de um EditText

Tags: android

Sou iniciante em android e o max que consegui fazer até agora é ao apertar o botão salvar ele imprime no log oque eu escrevi, mas não estou conseguindo armazenar isto em uma variavel.

```
  package com.example.igor.blocodenotas;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by Igor on 19/05/2016.
 */
public class Dialogobox extends DialogFragment{
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle saveInstanceState){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("Insira sua anotação:");
        // DECLARACAO DO EDITTEXT
        final EditText anotacao = new EditText(getActivity());
        builder.setView(anotacao);


        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancelar,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"você clicou em cancelar",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.salvar,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
               Log.v("EditText",anotacao.getText().toString());
            }
        });
        Dialog dialog=builder.create();

        return dialog;
    }
}
```

Comment: Declare uma variável do tipo String e depois para armazenar use: `nomeVariavel = anotacao.getText().toString();`

Comment: Consegui, obrigado, eu estava tentando desta forma mas colocando o nome da variavel de anotacao tb por isso n dava certo